# Authentication Problem - not recognizing 'else' - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong here. I have implemented the [Super Simple Authentication](http://railscasts.com/episodes/21-super-simple-authentication) from Ryan Bates tutorial and while the login portion is functioning correctly, I can't get an error message and redirect to happen correctly for a bad login.

Ryan Bates admits in his comments he left this out but can't seem to implement his recommendation. Basically what is happening is that when someone logs in correctly it works. When a bad password is entered it does the same redirect and flashes 'successfully logged in' thought they are not. The admin links do not show (which is correct and are the links protected by the <% if admin? %>) but I need it to say 'failed login' and redirect to login path. Here is my code:

SessionsController

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      if 
      session[:password] = params[:password]
      flash[:notice] = 'Successfully logged in'
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = "whoops"
      redirect_to login_path
    end
  end

    def destroy
      reset_session
      flash[:notice] = 'Successfully logged out'
      redirect_to posts_path
    end
  end
```

ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  helper_method :admin?

  protected

  def authorize
    unless admin?
      flash[:error] = "unauthorized request"
      redirect_to posts_path
      false
    end
  end

  def admin?
    session[:password] == "123456"
  end

  helper :all # include all helpers, all the time
  protect_from_forgery # See ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection for details
  # 
end
```

Comment: is it just a typo? should not have a newline after the 'if' keyword?

Comment: tried moving the session[password] up to same line but no go.

Comment: Hi there. 

Does your code read if session[:password] = session[:password] or has SO garbled your code?

Comment: should be == not =

if session[:password] == params[:password] then
  ...

Comment: So the addition of the == vs = is not working either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You need to use Ruby's comparison operator `==` rather than the assignment operator `=`. Your `create` action should be:</strike>

```
def create 
  if session[:password] == params[:password] 
    flash[:notice] = 'Successfully logged in' 
    redirect_to posts_path 
  else 
    flash[:notice] = "whoops" 
    redirect_to login_path 
  end 
end
```

---

**Edit:** The problem is that nowhere in your `SessionsController` are you actually checking the entered password against the correct password. Change your `create` method to this:

```
def create 
  if params[:password] == '123456'
    session[:password] = params[:password]
    flash[:notice] = 'Successfully logged in' 
    redirect_to posts_path 
  else 
    flash[:notice] = "whoops" 
    redirect_to login_path 
  end 
end
```

It's not ideal having the password hard-coded like this and storing it in the session for use by the `admin?` helper method, but this is supposed to be *super simple authentication*.

Comment: Hi John, that doesn't seem to be working either. Still redirects and flashes 'successfully logged in' even though they are not.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my typo in the title as well.

Comment: Perfect, that worked great. I know this isn't a great way but want to make sure I understand how this all works before moving on. I will likely by install gem clearance next. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it worked. This is approach is fine for simple stuff, but you probably wouldn't want to build an online banking application using it! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
    if  #YOU MISSING SOMETHING HERE WHICH Returns TRUE IF USER IS VALID
      session[:password] = session[:password]
      flash[:notice] = 'Successfully logged in'
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = "invalid login"  #CHange if messaage for invalid login
      redirect_to login_path
    end
```

it must be

```
    if   session[:password] == params[:password]
```

Comment: Yea, I had a typo there. Still not working even with that change.

Answer (score 0):

You never have a fail condition due to:

```
if session[:password] = session[:password]
```

This will always be true. You probably want something like:

```
if session[:password] == 'canihazpasswrd' then
  do_something_here
```

Comment: I think you have a typo here. What's the point of setting a password in the session if it's already present?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Refer @john's answer. :)

Try this:

```
  def create
    if session[:password] == '123456'
      flash[:notice] = 'Succesfully logged in'
      redirect_to home_path
     else
      flash[:notice] = "Incorrect Password!"
      redirect_to login_path
    end
  end
```

Comment: The `admin?` method should just return whether the user is an administrator or not by comparing the password stored in the session against the known correct password. You can't use the assignment operator within an `if` statement as your `create` method does.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I copy pasted from the question! :P

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the tutorial you used does no user's authentication. It only checks if the login belongs to an admin, so some content will be showed.

This way you'll never have wrong login/password, just admin/non-admin.